Field special characters validation
How to validate special characters using Filehelpers attribute (when using multirecord engine)
I'm using a multirecord engine and record defined as:
public class MyEngine : IRecordEngineFactory
{
    public MultiRecordEngine CreateMultiRecordEngine()
    {
        return new MultiRecordEngine(
            typeof(Header),
            typeof(RecordTypeA),
            typeof(RecordTypeB),
            typeof(Footer));
    }
}

[FixedLengthRecord]
public record RecordTypeA
{
 [FieldFixedLength(10)]
 public int UserName { get; set; }
 
 [FieldFixedLength(20)]
 [MyCustomValidator]
 public int UserAddress { get; set; }
}

Then I use my engine as:
var myGenerator = new UserFileGenerator(new MyEngine());

using var stream = myGenerator.Write(userObject);

Is there a way to build the custom attribute by inheriting any class/interface and overriding any Filehelpers method that is exposed ?

MyCustomValidator

Then I can apply that to RecordTypeA fields ?
In the attribute logic I want to validate the field (in this case the user address) to not have certain special characters. If special characters are found then I need to throw an exception to stop further processing when the engine writes the stream.

myEngine.WriteStream(stream, file);


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
